# Easiest proof of existence of non-Lebesgue-measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, education

I want to show a general audience of educated non-mathematicians that there are non-Lebesgue measurable subsets of $[0,1)$.

I think that (most of) my audience could follow the construction of the [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set), if I present it carefully enough. And that's the easiest proof I'm aware of.

Does anyone know an even easier proof?

Comment: Certainly not. An easier proof would have entered books on Measure Theory. If you want an easire one I think you should invent one.

Comment: @geetha290krm Sometimes some proofs don't find its way to text books. There's a very easy proof of the Schröder–Bernstein theorem that is not in most used Set Theory books.

Comment: It is hardly an intuitive result and it uses the Axiom of Choice, so perhaps a little hard for non mathematicians to appreciated. Perhaps the Banach Tarski 'paradox' would be  more illustrative :-).

Comment: @copper.hat But is the Banach-Tarski paradox easier to prove? I could state it easily enough, but the constructions I'm aware of would be harder for my audience than the 1-d case.

Comment: @geetha290krm Fair enough. I didn't have high hopes to find an easier proof, but I thought it was worth checking here. I will also give it some thought and report back if I figure something out!

Comment: @aduh No, the proof is not easier, but the idea is possibly more digestible.

Comment: I kind of think the Banach-Tarski paradox goes well as a sort of postscript to the existence of non-Lebesgue measurable sets.  Once you show that you can do voodoo with translation invariant measures, the paradox becomes a little easier for the audience to swallow, even without a proof.